# Cleaning SEC filings

Tags: python, html, edgar

I am currently trying to clean 10-K filings (2690 to be exact) in order to get the pure text (without html-tags etc.). Among others, I would like to calculate the readability scores in a next step. However, cleaning the text is becoming a larger problem than I thought. Since it is recommended to not use Regex for html-files, I tried BeautifulSoup with the get_text method:

```
response = requests.get(r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/827054/0000827054-14-000140.txt")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
text = soup.get_text(' ',strip = True)
```

This works fine for a small portion of the text, but then I get the following mess:

```
:</font></div><div style="line-height:120%;text-align:left;text-indent:48px;font-size:10pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:10pt;"><br clear="none"/></font></div><div style="line-height:120%;text-align:center;font-size:10pt;"><div style="padding-left:0px;text-indent:0px;line-height:normal;padding-top:10px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left;"><tr><td colspan="12" rowspan="1"></td></tr><tr><td width="65%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="9%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="9%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="9%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-ali:</font></div><div style="line-height:120%;text-align:left;text-indent:48px;font-size:10pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:10pt;"><br clear="none"/></font></div><div style="line-height:120%;text-align:center;font-size:10pt;"><div style="padding-left:0px;text-indent:0px;line-height:normal;padding-top:10px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left;"><tr><td colspan="12" rowspan="1"></td></tr><tr><td width="65%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="9%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="9%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="9%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td><td width="1%" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom;padding-left:2px;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><div style="overflow:hidden;font-size:10pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;gn:bottom;padding-left:2px;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><div style="overflow:hidden;font-size:10pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;
```

Is there an elegant solution to this problem or do I have to use Regex and try to get the text in a version that can be used for further analysis?